# iphone 6s camera calibration parameters

Tags: ros, calibration, camera, 3d-slam, lsd-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I get camera calibration parameters for iphone 6s? I need the following intrinsic parameters:

Cam_fx: normalized focal length in x

Cam_fy: normalized focal length in y

Cam_cx: normalized camera center in x

Cam_cy: normalized camera center in y

Cam_s: normalized distortion factor

I tried using the [PTAM](http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_ptam/Tutorials/camera_calibration) camera calibration process but im getting some errors. Can anyone please suggest me some other way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259458/iphone-6s-camera-calibration-parameters/) by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 272 on 2017-04-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After trying a few tools recommended here and various sources, the one that worked end to end is provided by the [MRPT](http://www.mrpt.org/list-of-mrpt-apps/application_camera-calib/) project.

It uses the pinhole method to calibrate the camera. It has worked fine on an iPhone 5, although I have little practice with the generated parameters at this point.

---

Originally posted by [ic](https://answers.ros.org/users/30936/ic/) with karma: 26 on 2017-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1